# Scopes in JavaScript - correct to conceptualize as a tree?

Tags: javascript

Would it be accurate to conceptualise the scopes present in a codebase at runtime as a tree?

```
var a;

function Foo() {
  var b;  

  function Bar() {
    var c;
  }

  function Bam() {
    var d;
  }
}
```

Tracing the scopes in this code:

```
global -> Foo --> Bar
               |
               -> Bam
```

Or is this conceptualisation broken by things like closures?

Comment: Sort of.  Unless a closure is created, only one branch of the tree exists at any given time.  The scope of `Bar()` doesn't exist until it is called and then lasts only for the duration of the execution of `Bar()` unless a closure is created that causes Bar's scope to last longer.  With closure's it is further complicated by the fact that you could have N different scopes saved for a closure, not just one which again isn't a simple tree.  That would be more like a tree where each node could be a single scope or an array of scopes.

Comment: So scope is a runtime concept only? Surely scope can be reasoned about before runtime? At runtime only one branch of the tree will be "active", but *conceptually* the other possible scopes "exist" to reason about.

Comment: scope is purely determined at compile time. What closures do is that they let you have multiple "Bar" scopes side by side.

Comment: In a Javascript implementation, a scope is an actual runtime object that is created when a function is invoked and is then garbage collected when there are no longer any references to it (e.g. when the function has finished executing and no closures were created that still have a reference to it).  Yes, programmers must reason about what the scope will be at runtime and that's how they write code, but in Javascript it isn't an entirely static thing (unlike a strictly compiled language like C++) so I think it is misleading to think it has one and only one static representation.

Comment: @jfriend00 Are you talking about Lexical Environments and Environment Records? (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) If so these are surely related to, impacted by but separate to scopes.

Comment: It is true that the variables that are going to be in scope when a given function is run are known at compile time and at code writing time so if that's what you're trying to document, you can use the tree concept.  Closures are very worth understanding though and they have a more dynamic nature.

Comment: @Ben - in your mind and question, what is the difference between lexical environment and scope?  I guess, I'm suddenly not sure what exactly you're asking about.  I think of scope as a dynamic thing that is created at runtime (there are actual dynamic scope objects in a JS implementation) and closures cause some scopes to last long durations and can even make some scopes have multiple copies.  I thought that's what you were asking about.  What variables you can access from any given code is more of a lexical thing and is determined at compile time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am hypothesising that scope is a lexical concept that can be visualized as a tree regardless of closures. Hence scopes *are* static. Some categories of variable visibility on the other hand, for example variable closure is separate to scope (although it is affected by lexical, static, scope). This is the question I am asking.

Comment: @jfriend00  "I think of scope as a dynamic thing that is created at runtime (there are actual dynamic scope objects in a JS implementation) and closures cause some scopes to last long durations and can even make some scopes have multiple copies" This is the crux of my question. Is this actually completely true? Or is scope subtly different to variable visibility?

Comment: In C++, scope is purely lexical.  In Javascript, it is a bit more powerful than that because of closures.  If you want to think of it as purely lexical, go right ahead.  The variables you can access from any given piece of code are determined purely by lexical context.  But, I think it's beneficial to understand the dynamic nature of a scope object in JS because that gives you a much clearer understanding how how closures work, their lifetime, how they can best be used, consequences of using them, etc...  At runtime, there are actual scope objects that are garbage collected.

Comment: For me, I only fully understood closures when I started thinking of garbage collected function scope objects.  When there's a lasting reference to something in the inner frame of a function (usually do to a local callback that something can call in the future), then the function scope can't be garbage collected (because some code that is still in play has a reference into it) and thus we have a closure.  As soon as those lasting references are gone, the scope will be garbage collected and the closure will be cleaned up.  This is what made closures 100% clear to me.

Comment: It's like the `prototype`/`[[Prototype]]` discussion all over again ;) There is a property on `Functions` `[[Scope]]` that is a `LexicalEnvironment` that in some sense encodes rules for determining variable visibility. I understand your POV. I currently believe the `LexicalEnvironment` instance to be based upon the lexical scopes, rather than defining or extending them.

Comment: No disagreement there.  The lexical environment (what variables can be accessed) is determined at compile time.  The lifetime of those environments (which is what I think of as scope objects) is influenced by the running code at runtime.  Your use of the term "scope" caused me to think of the runtime objects that JS uses which are more dynamic than a fixed tree.  The possible lexical environment is a fixed tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the scope is a tree. I wonder what scope graph with cycles or that is a DAG would mean :)

As for closures, the scope is still purely lexical. Even if you save the closure on a variable or store it on some array, the scope of the variables are still the variables around where the function was originally defined.

Comment: OK as I thought. So closures are a discrete concept along with execution contexts etc.

Comment: ...and the active branch in the tree corresponds to the scope chain?

Comment: You're forgetting `with` statements :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your graph in the question is correct. Let us understand it with the list of variables available in each function,

```
var a;

function Foo() {
    var b;
    # [a, b]

    function Bar() {
        var c;
        # [a, b, c]
    }

    function Bam() {
        var d;
        # [a, b, d]
    }
}
```

In `Foo`, `a` is available from the higher scope and it has `b` defined in it. `Bar` has access to `a` also, it can access `Foo`'s `b` because of the closure property, but it cannot access `Bam`'s `d`, because it is enclosed in `Bam` and not visible outside. Similarly `Bam` cannot access `Bar`'s `c`.

1. Actually, when `Foo` is created, there will be a new *Lexical environment*  created (which has a *Environment Record* and a reference to outer Lexical Environment) and all the variables created in it will be stored in the Environment Record. Since `Foo` doesn't have any outer Environment, outer Lexical Environment will be Global Environment.
2. Similarly when `Bar` is created a new Lexical Environment will be created which will have the outer Lexical Environment as the `Foo`'s Lexical Environment. So, when a variable being accessed in `Bar` is not defined in the current Environment Record, then `Foo`'s Environment Record will be searched.

Similarly for `Bam`.

Quoting [ECMA Script 5.1 Specification](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2),

> A Lexical Environment is a specification type used to define the association of Identifiers to specific variables and functions based upon the lexical nesting structure of ECMAScript code. A Lexical Environment consists of an Environment Record and a possibly null reference to an outer Lexical Environment. Usually a Lexical Environment is associated with some specific syntactic structure of ECMAScript code such as a FunctionDeclaration, a WithStatement, or a Catch clause of a TryStatement and a new Lexical Environment is created each time such code is evaluated.
>
> An Environment Record records the identifier bindings that are created within the scope of its associated Lexical Environment.
>
> The outer environment reference is used to model the logical nesting of Lexical Environment values. The outer reference of a (inner) Lexical Environment is a reference to the Lexical Environment that logically surrounds the inner Lexical Environment. An outer Lexical Environment may, of course, have its own outer Lexical Environment. A Lexical Environment may serve as the outer environment for multiple inner Lexical Environments. For example, if a FunctionDeclaration contains two nested FunctionDeclarations then the Lexical Environments of each of the nested functions will have as their outer Lexical Environment the Lexical Environment of the current execution of the surrounding function.

Comment: "Since Foo doesn't have any outer Environment, outer Lexical Environment will be null." So there is no root "original" Lexical Environment?

Comment: @Ben Ah, good catch. It will be Global Environment. It is defined in the specification [here](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3). Only the global environment's outer lexical environment will be `null`.